# How to do an exact match followed by ORDER BY in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, case-when, columnsorting

I'm trying to write a query that puts some results (in my case a single result) at the top, and then sorts the rest. I have yet to find a PostgreSQL solution.

Say I have a table called `airports` like so.

```
 id | code |        display_name         
----+------+----------------------------
  1 | SDF  | International               
  2 | INT  | International Airport       
  3 | TES  | Test                        
  4 | APP  | Airport Place International
```

In short, I have a query in a controller method that gets called asynchronously when a user text searches for an airport either by `code` or `display_name`. However, when a user types in an input that matches a `code` exactly (airport code is unique), I want that result to appear first, and all airports that also have `int` in their `display_name` to be displayed afterwards in ascending order. If there is no exact match, it should return any wildcard matches sorted by `display_name` ascending. So if a user types in `INT`, The row `(2, INT, International Airport)` should be returned first followed by the others:

```
Results:
1. INT | International Airport
2. APP | Airport Place International
3. SDF | International
```

Here's the kind of query I was tinkering with that is slightly simplified to make sense outside the context of my application but same concept nonetheless.

```
SELECT * FROM airports
WHERE display_name LIKE 'somesearchtext%'
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN a.code = 'somesearchtext` THEN a.code ELSE a.display_name END)
```

Right now the results if I type `INT` I'm getting

```
Results:
1. APP | Airport Place International
2. INT | International Airport
3. SDF | International
```

My `ORDER BY` must be incorrect but I can't seem to get it
Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want an exact match on `code` to return first, then I think this does the trick:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM airports a
WHERE a.display_name LIKE 'somesearchtext%'
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN a.code = 'somesearchtext' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
         a.display_name
```

You could also write this as:

```
ORDER BY (a.code = 'somesearchtext') DESC, a.display_name
```

This isn't standard SQL, but it is quite readable.

Comment: Note you don't need the CASE. Since "=" returns a boolean and TRUE sorts after FALSE, you can do "ORDER BY a.code='yourvalue' DESC, a.display_name"

Comment: ORDER BY (a.code != 'somesearchtext') also works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve your goal by using a UNION. 
First get an exact match and then add that result to rest of the data as you which.

e.g.. (you will need to work in this a bit)

```
SELECT * FROM airports
WHERE code == 'somesearchtext'
ORDER BY display_name 

UNION

SELECT * FROM airports
WHERE code != 'somesearchtext' AND display_name LIKE 'somesearchtext%'
ORDER BY display_name
```