# How to sort a queryset by its Q objects order?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I've a simple searching form and view:

```
# forms.py
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    q = forms.CharField(label='Search', max_length=1024, required=False)


# views.py
def search(request):
    
    search_form = forms.SearchForm()
    q = ''
    
    if request.method == 'GET':
        search_form = forms.SearchForm(request.GET)
        
        if search_form.is_valid():
            q = search_form.cleaned_data['q']
            
    products = models.Product.objects.filter(publication_status='published')
    
    if q.strip() != '': # If there's something to search for which not whitespaces
        products = products.filter(
            Q(title__contains=q) |
            Q(description__contains=q) |
            Q(main__name__contains=q) |
            Q(sub__contains=q)
            )

    context = {
        'products': products,
        'search_form':search_form,
        }
    return render(request, 'search.html', context=context)



# search.html
{% if products %}
<h3>Products:</h3>

<ul>
  {% for p in products %}
    <li><ul>
      <li><a href="{% url 'product' p.pk %}">{{ p }}</a></li>
      <li>{{ p.description }}</li>
      <li><a href="{% url 'main' p.main.pk %}">{{ p.main }}</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url 'sub' p.main.pk p.sub %}">{{ p.sub|verbose }}</a></li>
    </ul></li><br>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<h3>No products found matching your search!</h3>
{% endif %}
```

If the word "polo" is the title of product 2 and it's also the description of the product 1,
The problem is when I'm trying to search for that word, The product 1 is rendered in the first place in the template (because it's the first matching).

What I'm trying to do is to sort the queryset first by title then by description then by sub category, so the product 2 is rendered first (because the queryset is sorted by its Q objects order)

Comment: Not sure what you want exactly but you can do: **products = products.order_by('title', 'description', 'main__name', 'sub')** ?

Comment: This will sort the query set ascending by title then description.. so on , I'm trying to order the products which matched by title at first then the products which matched by description next and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use custom order_by

for more info about creating custom order, you can read this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45418407/how-to-do-an-exact-match-followed-by-order-by-in-postgresql)
and for Django model things this [page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/)

```py
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value


custom_order=Case(
        When(title__contains=q, then=Value(1)),
        When(description__contains=q, then=Value(2)),
        When(main__name__contains=q, then=Value(3)),
        When(sub__contains=q, then=Value(4)))
        
products.filter(
            Q(title__contains=q) |
            Q(description__contains=q) |
            Q(main__name__contains=q) |
            Q(sub__contains=q)
            ).order_by(custom_order)
```

Answer (score 0):

@lucas-grugru give you already a perfect answer:

```
# views.py
def search(request):
    
    query= Q(publication_status='published')
    ordering = ''
    
    search_form = forms.SearchForm(request.GET)  # you dont need to check it get or post.
    if search_form.is_valid():
        search_dict = dict.fromkeys(search_keys, search_form.cleaned_data['q'])
        query &= Q(_connector=Q.OR, *search_dict)
        ordering = Сase(When({key:q, then=Value(idx)) for idx, (key, q) in enumerate(search_dict.items()))            
    
    products = models.Product.objects.filter(query)          
    context = {
        'products': products.order_by(ordering) if ordering else products,
        'search_form':search_form,
        }
    return render(request, 'search.html', context=context)
```

I made `if ordering`, because ordering is not a free operation. Each field you add to the ordering incurs a cost to your database. Each foreign key you add will implicitly include all of its default orderings as well.

don't forget, you can clean `q` in form:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    q = forms.CharField(label='Search', max_length=1024, required=False)

    def clean_q(self):
        q = (self.cleaned_data.get('q') or '').strip()
        if q:
            return q
        raise ValidationError("Nothing to search")
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort I appreciate it, but the answer have many TypeErrors and SyntaxErrors.